# WHMCS database replication

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am moving my website to a high available cluster, it involves a WordPress multi-site and a WHMCS installation. In my WordPress configuration, I have two databases a master-master replication.

For WordPress there is a plugin to distribute the load amongst those DB servers, called HyperDB. But for WHMCS I don't really know what to do, or what is the best practice for doing this. WHMCS connects to its database just like WordPress with a config file where the credentials are stored.

So basically, what is the best method for load balancing replicated MySQL databases that receive reads and writes on multiple hosts? Eventually maybe even multiple data centers.

Answer (score 0):

Master to Maser replication should make this possible. And there is no need for a plugin.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html

You can also do load balancing, using a load balancer and multiple mysql servers.

https://www.howtoforge.com/loadbalanced_mysql_cluster_debian

There are a lot of different configurations that can make what you're attempting to do possible, google the above methods and you should find your solution quickly.